# What is the problem with my haskell code?

Tags: haskell, boolean

> Implement some :: [Bool] -> Bool function that decides conditions a list of whether it has a true element. In this task, the or function its use is not permitted.

- Test:
- some [succ 'a' / = 'b', 1 + 1 / = 2, 10 <20] == True
- some [succ 'a' / = 'b', 1 + 1 / = 2, 10> = 20] == False
- some [] == False

```
some :: [Bool] -> Bool
some [] = False
some (False: _) = False
some (_: False) = False
some _ = True
```

How can I fix my code ? I do not know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```hs
some :: [Bool] -> Bool
some [] = False
some (False:xs) = some xs
some (True:_) = True
```

The problem with your current code is that you don't recurse further if you see the first element is `False`. When you see a `False` you have to continue checking the rest of the list up until either the list is exhausted or you find a `True`. Whenever you find a `True` you can bail out early and just return a `True` because you don't care about the rest.

Answer (score 2):

In the pattern `(x:xs)`, `x` is the first item of the list, and `xs` is a list of the remaining elements. Such list can *not* be `False`. It is possible a list full of `False` values, but not a `Bool`.

You `some` thus looks like:

```
some :: [Bool] -> Bool
some [] = False
some (x:xs) = x || some xs
```